# How to rebuild the whole view in flutter everytime view enters the screen

Tags: flutter

I want my page to hit the API always whenever it enters a page.
For example, I am having 2 screens i.e FirstSCreen and SecondScreen.
In FirstScreen I am calling an API to fetch some data. So if the user navigates from FirstScreen to SecondScreen and then comes back to FirstScreen by pressing the back button It should hit the API in FirstScreen again.

I want to know is there any inbuilt function in flutter where I should call my methods so that it can work every time it enters the screen. I have tried using  **didUpdateWidget()** but it is not working the way I want.

initState() is also called only once the widget is loaded ..
Please explain me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an example that might help. However, it might not cover all scenarios where your `FirstScreen` will always call a specific function whenever the page is displayed after coming from a different page/screen, or specifically resuming the app (coming from background -- not to be confused when coming from another screen or popping).

My example however, will always call a function when you come back from a specific screen, and you can re-implement it  to other navigation functions to ensure that a specific function is always called when coming back to `FirstScreen` from other screens.

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

home_page.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()))
                  .then((value) => _reload(value)),
              child: Text('Navigate to Next Page'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _reload(var value) async {
    print(
        'Home Page resumed after popping/closing SecondPage with value {$value}. Do something.');
  }
}
```

second_page.dart

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pop(context, 'Passed Value');

        /// It's important that returned value (boolean) is false,
        /// otherwise, it will pop the navigator stack twice;
        /// since Navigator.pop is already called above ^
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text('Second Page')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `async await` for it. Let's say you have a button that change the route.

```
onPressed: () async {
  await Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SecondScreen(),
      ),
  );
  ApiCall();
},
```

The `ApiCall` function will call only when user push the back on the second screen.

Comment: the scenario is like on Secondscreen I am changing the data on the basis of user selection and I am passing that id in the API that is being called in FirstScreen. So once Secondscreen get popped up It should trigger the API again in FirstSCreen with the id that user selected in SecondScreen 
Note:I am using local storage to store that id .

Comment: Thуn you have several options to do it.

The first is sending the id with pop. From the second screen to the first screen.

On the second screen:

    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, id);
      },
      child: Text('Save'),
    )

On the first screen:

    onPressed: () async {
      Final id = await Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondScreen(),
          ),
      );
      ApiCall(id);
    },

Comment: The second is load the id from you storage at the first screen.

On the second screen:

    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
      LocalStorage.save(id)
        Navigator.pop(context, id);
      },
      child: Text('Save'),
    )

On the first screen:

    onPressed: () async {
      final id = await Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondScreen(),
          ),
      );

     Final id = LocalStorage.load()

      ApiCall(id);
    },

Comment: Or you can use something for as global state managment. (Provider, Bloc.. etc). Then you make an api call on the second screen and show it on the first.

Answer (score 1):

@Rick's answer works like a charm even for Riverpod state management as I coul d not get the firstscreen to rebuild to show changes to the 'used' status of a coupon on the second screen where there is a button to use it.
So I did on the details page:

```
 return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        //final dumbo = ref.read(userProvider.notifier).initializeUser();
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return false; //true;
      },
```

Then on the coupons list page, each coupon card has:

```
child: Card(
                            elevation: 10,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                              side: BorderSide(
                                  color: coupons[index].isUsed
                                      ? Colors.grey
                                      : Colors.blue),
                            ),
                            child: InkWell(
                              splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
                              onTap: () {
                                //go to Details screen with Coupon instance
                                //https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/details',
                                        arguments: coupons[index].couponId)
                                    .then((_) => _reload());
                                /*Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (_) => DetailsScreen(
                                      coupon: coupons[index],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );*/
                              },
```

where I used `_` since there is no parameter.
Then the function in class CouponScreen is:

```
void _reload() {
     
    setState(() {});
  }
```

I believe `setState(){}` is what triggers the rebuild.  I apologize for the formatting but it's very difficult to copy and paste Flutter code that is nested deeply.